# Normalize a pairwise similarity matrix so that it sums to 1

Tags: r, matrix

I have a symmetric similarity matrix that I want to use as input into Rtsne (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/index.html).

```
library(Matrix)

example <- data.frame(Source = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
                      Target = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                      Similarity = c(0,0.003,0.0541,0.29,0.0001,0.003,0,0.0123,0.104,
                                     0,0.0541,0.0123,0,0.0067,0.31,0.29,0.104,0.0067,
                                     0,0.0098,0.0001,0,0.31,0.0098,0))
mat <- as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = example$Source,
                             j = example$Target,
                             x = example$Similarity))

dimnames(mat) <- list(Source = unique(example$Source), 
                     Target = unique(example$Target))
```

According to the original author of the t-SNE procedure, a similarity matrix should be symmetrized and **normalized to sum up to one** (https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/)

> **Can I use a pairwise similarity matrix as input into t-SNE?**
>
> Yes you can! For instance, we successfully applied t-SNE on a dataset of word association data. >Download the Matlab implementation, make sure the diagonal of the pairwise similarity matrix contains >only zeros, symmetrize the pairwise similarity matrix, and normalize it to sum up to one. You can now >use the result as input into the tsne_p.m function.

I'm unsure how to normalize the matrix to sum up to one. Further does this mean that each row sums to one, each column sums to one, or the entire matrix sums to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divide the matrix by the total of its sum

```
mat <- mat/sum(mat)
```

then we can check

```
sum(mat)
[1] 1
```